# How to go forward with this PCA result?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca

I've done my preliminary PCA with this code

```r
library(readxl)
Pca_for_R <- read_excel("~/Pca for R.xlsx")
Mypca <- prcomp(Pca_for_R, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

I got 15 PCs for this and I found that 6 PCs over eigen value 1 is required to go forward

[image: This is the image of my output PCS]

I now want to be able to reduce from PC 15 to PC6 and reduce even further based on the loadings I get. The aim is to reduce the number of PCs to use in cluster analysis.

Comment: What have you tried in cluster analysis ?

Comment: Have a look at docs https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/prcomp . You can set `rank` to get the first six PCs.

Comment: @Basti- I still havent tried cluster analysis yet. I want to be able to know the right function to use to minimize my component loadings further.

Comment: @Rm4n- Thank you, Yes using rank I got the first 6 PCS, but some of my variables load higher in components between 7 to 15. How do I go about with that?

Comment: @JannetPhilip AFAIK, PCA is a lossy transformation and in your case you're losing ~39% of the information. If you're fine with this (your clustering is meaningful), you can proceed, otherwise increase the number of PCs until you're satisfied.